# Mocking a method in an element of a list

Tags: java, mockito

I have this code in my Subject Under Test:

```
public class Widget {
    private Set<Thing> things;
    public Set<Thing> getThings() { return things; }
    public void setThings(Set<Thing> things) { this.things = things; }

    public void performAction(PerformingVisitor performer) {
        for (Thing thing: getThings())
        {
            thing.perform(performer);
        }
    }
}
```

My JUnit/Mockito test looks like:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class WidgetTest {
    @Mock private PerformingVisitor performer;
    @Mock private Thing thing;
    @InjectMocks private Widget widget;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        Set<Thing> things = new HashSet<Thing>();
        things.add(thing);
        widget.setThings(things);

        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldPerformThing() {
        Mockito.when(thing.perform(Mockito.any(PerformingVisitor.class))).thenReturn(true);

        widget.performAction(performer);

        Mockito.verify(thing).perform(Mockito.any(PerformingVisitor.class));
    }
}
```

However, this gives me the error:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
thing.perform(<any>);
    -> at com.myclass.ThingTest.shouldPerformThing(WidgetTest.java:132)
```

I've verified that the code enters the `for` loop and should be calling the actual `thing.perform(performer);` line, but my mock does not seem to be recording a call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `initMocks` before the mock injection.

Could you try to change your setUp method for this:

```
   @Before
   public void setUp() throws Exception {
      MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
      Set<Thing> things = new HashSet<Thing>();
      things.add(thing);
      widget.setThings(things); 
   }
```

Hope it works

Comment: It works but the statement `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` is useless.

Answer (score 1):

From the `MockitoJUnitRunner` [javadoc](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/runners/MockitoJUnitRunner.html):

> Initializes mocks annotated with Mock, so that explicit usage of MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(Object) is not necessary.

So, if you remove

```
 MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
```

from your `setUp` method, the test pass.